# How to activate the VOLTE by using my second sim card data connection

Tags: voip, lte

I have Huawei p30 pro and I was able to setup the VOLTE function perfectly. The VOLTE can work perfectly once my phone connected to any via  network.

The problem is that I need to activate the VOLTE by using my second sim card data connection not by using WİFİ data connection.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the P30's dual SIM support is limited to the secondary SIM (The one that's not used for the default data connection) to only support Circuit Switched traffic.

This is fairly common on dual SIM phones, it means less processing and battery use, but it means you can't use VoLTE which relies on Packet Switched traffic.